# Crear un gráfico con datos de varias columnas en un eje con seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Tengo un DataFrame del tipo:

> nombre | genero | categoria | t_lecturaN1 | t_lecturaN2 | t_lecturaN3 |

y quiero un gráfico que me muestre en el eje <kbd>y</kbd> los tres tiempos `{t_lecturaN1,t_lecturaN2y t_lecturaN3}` y en eje <kbd>x</kbd> solo tiempo.

Lo que he conseguido con el siguiente código es algo así:

```
sns.catplot(x='t_lecturaN1', y='genero', hue='categoria', data=df,
            palette='hls', kind='box'
            )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi eje <kbd>y</kbd> sea la información de las columnas <kbd>t_lecturaN1</kbd>, <kbd>t_lecturaN2</kbd> y <kbd>t_lecturaN3</kbd> y mi eje <kbd>x</kbd> solo me muestre tiempo? El `hue` sería lo mismo, que me muestre categorías.

Solo coloque en <kbd>y</kbd> el género para poder explicar mejor que ahí en vez de género quiero clasificar por <kbd>t_lecturaN1</kbd>, <kbd>t_lecturaN2</kbd> y <kbd>t_lecturaN3</kbd>...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo he entendido, puedes conseguir lo que deseas con [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). La idea es pivotar las columnas `t_lectura_Nx`, conformando los valores de una nueva columna, los tiempos pasarían a otra columna.

Es decir, quedaría el Dataframe algo así:

> ```
>         nombre    genero      categoria    t_lectura  time
>      0       a         M         alumno  t_lecturaN1   175
>      1       b         M        experto  t_lecturaN1   107
>      2       c         M  universitario  t_lecturaN1   120
>      3       b         M        experto  t_lecturaN2   110
>      4       c         M  universitario  t_lecturaN2   110
>      5       d         M  universitario  t_lecturaN2   125
>      6       b         M        experto  t_lecturaN3    85
>      7       c         M  universitario  t_lecturaN3   115
>      8       d         M  universitario  t_lecturaN3   110
> ```

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Datos para probar, sin sentido alguno
data = {"nombre": ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
                   "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"
                   ),
        "genero": ("M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F",
                   "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M"
                   ), 
        "categoria": ("alumno", "experto", "universitario",
                      "universitario", "experto", "alumno",
                      "alumno", "experto", "universitario",
                      "experto", "alumno", "experto",
                      "alumno", "universitario"
                      ),
        "t_lecturaN1": (175, 107, 120, 130, 100, 170, 98,
                        175, 107, 120, 130, 100, 170, 98
                        ),
        "t_lecturaN2": (182, 110, 110, 125, 114, 162,105,
                        182, 110, 110, 125, 114, 162,105
                        ), 
        "t_lecturaN3": (177, 85, 115, 110, 75, 156, 80,
                        177, 85, 115, 110, 75, 156, 80
                        )
        }


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.melt(id_vars=("nombre", "genero", "categoria"),
             value_name="time",
             var_name="t_lectura"
             )
sb.catplot(x='time', y='t_lectura', hue='categoria', data=df,
           palette='hls', kind='box'
           )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente!!!!!!! funcionó perfecto! muchas gracias :D